# Is there an "is logged-in" endpoint in Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Is there any endpoint to check if the user is logged in or not in the OAuth Server? What I want is a client-server request to check if the user is loggedin in the OAuth Server in order to redirect him after.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a `GET` request on `/api/user`

Comment: True, but I want also an "not-logged-in" response aswell which I cant get from /api/user

Comment: I would assume if you get a ```401``` then you are not logged in